# Find missing table by comparing two different databases

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to find a missing table in a database.

**I have two databases:**

1. database_1 (It contains **120 tables**)
2. database_1_backup  (It contains **121 tables**)

**What I have done so far:**

I found the list of tables in two databases by using the following sql query:

```
show tables;
```

Using the tables list, I made two text files, then compared two textfiles. That is how I found the missing table (That was a time-consuming task, so).

Is there any query available to find missing table by comparing two
 databases?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use aggregation to find tables missing in *either* database:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME,
       (CASE WHEN SUM(TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbname1') = 0
             THEN 'Missing in dbname1'
             ELSE 'Missing in dbname2'
        END) as which
FROM information_schema.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA IN ('dbname1', 'dbname2')
GROUP BY TABLE_NAME
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
ORDER BY TABLE_NAME;
```

Answer (score 2):

Querying `information_schema.TABLES` should give you the answer you are looking for, try this to find to missing table:

```
SELECT table_name     
FROM information_schema.TABLES 
WHERE table_schema = 'database_1_backup'
AND table_name NOT IN (
  SELECT table_name 
  FROM information_schema.TABLES
  WHERE table_schema = 'database_1'
);
```

Comment: It shows an error message  `#1054 - Unknown column 'schema_name' in 'where clause'`. Then I changed schema_name to table_schema in the where clause. Then worked. And thank you @jpw

Comment: @MjM Oh, my bad, was a typo.

Answer (score 1):

Run this query and just review the resulting COUNT column values.

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME,COUNT(*) 
FROM information_schema.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA IN('dbname1','dbname2')
GROUP BY TABLE_NAME
ORDER BY TABLE_NAME;
```